# Could you instruct a car thru the OBD port to open the trunk even if the car was turned off?

Tags: obd, trunk, accessories

Could you instruct a car thru the OBD port to open the trunk even if the car was turned off? Can you turn the accessories on from the port then open the trunk?

Comment: I suspect this is highly dependent on the make, model and year of the car @Bernie. Can you edit your question with these details?

Comment: So here is what I am thinking: If OnStar can pop the trunk on GM cars for Amazon, what if an ODB device could do the same universally?

Comment: On Star has direct access to the body control module. which does not turn off with the key.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/23047/obd-ii-power-when-key-not-in-ignition) response, when the ignition key is removed from the car it's usually not possible to communicate with the car via the OBD port so assuming by "turned off" you mean the ignition key removed, I'd say in most cases it is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen someone with a diagnostic tool (sort of like the one your mechanic uses, that has its own power supply) tell a car to open its trunk via the ODBII port.  The customer had locked their keys in the trunk and a roadside tech could open the door, but the security disabled the trunk release.

Being that roadside tech, I would dearly love to find such a tool.  Currently I have to open the car manually, then disassemble the door (on some cars) to access the lock and 'unlock' the car by manipulating the lock manually.  A PITA, to say the least.

Comment: If it was made easy, then the car could be stolen easily... Do you want your car stolen?

Answer (score -2):

The whole idea of the [On Board Diagnostics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics) port is to **provide** vehicle diagnostic information. It is read-only, except for specific log entries and specific fault codes that can be reset. It is not meant as a control interface for your car.

Also see [Can i control the brakes of a car by the OBD II Interface?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/51963/can-i-control-the-brakes-of-a-car-by-the-obd-ii-interface)

Comment: Not entirely true for all cases.  The Carly tool http://www.mycarly.com/product/bmw-app/   for BMW  can reprogram many operations of the vehicle. Of course what's available in the BMW may not be pure "OBD."

Comment: Actually you can flash the ecm via the obd2 port, and likely a lot of other things by accessing pid's. Dealerships do it all the time solving problems.

Comment: And, every time you clear codes, the reader has to communicate with the ECU to do it ... that's not one way comms either.

Comment: @Moab that often is done via another connector directly on the CAN bus instead of through the OBD port. But again, depends on manufacturer.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 just like i mentioned in my post, only some (not all) log entries and fault codes can be reset. Thats it.

Comment: This a pretty poor answer spoken like its fact but really is just flat out wrong. There is nothing "read-only" about an obd port. Its simply power,gnd and a connection into the data lines for the vehicle. Also, You can indeed control all types of car functions/actuation with good obd tools, Turn lights on/off, honk the horn, lock/unlock doors, switch relays on/off, cut off injectors, control the gauge needles in an instrument cluster. The list goes on and on depending on the make and year.Just today I was controlling all my hvac functions and vents through obd while diagnosing a a/c issue.

Comment: @MadMarky - please check out https://www.carhackingvillage.com/ and various videos of talks they have presented at Defcon or BSides. The OBD port in most cars can also be used to reprogram many functions